# Implement self hosted font in Material-UI custom theme (ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

At the moment I'm setting up my first project using Material-UI for ReactJS. As I want to customise the default theme with, for example, a custom font (hosted on the server, not Google Fonts or something similar) I started working on this.

However, while not getting any errors during build or in the browser console, it just does not load. I've already tried multiple proposed solutions from StackOverflow and the Material-UI repo but I cannot get it to work and as such I'm at a loss what to do next.

I've already tried several approaches that are suggested in other threads on StackOverflow, in the official Material-UI docs and in the issues on the Material-UI GitHub repository, but to no avail.
I'm probably overlooking something obvious, or scrambling different concepts so any help would be much appreciated :)

Theme definition:

```
import {createMuiTheme} from "@material-ui/core";

import Penna from "./../../assets/fonts/penna.otf";

const pennaFont = {
    fontFamily: 'Penna',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontDisplay: 'swap',
    fontWeight: 400,
    src: `
    local('Penna'),
    url(${Penna})
  `,
}

const MUI_THEME = createMuiTheme({
    typegraphy: {
        fontFamily: ['Penna', "'Helvetica Neue'", 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'].join(","),
        fontSize: "16px",
        fontWeightLight: "300",
        fontWeightRegular: "400",
        fontWeightMedium: "700",
    },
    overrides: {
        MuiCssBaseline: {
            '@global': {
                '@font-family': [pennaFont],
            },
        },
    },
});

export default MUI_THEME;
```

Top-level entry point:

```
// ReactJS related
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

// Material-UI
import {ThemeProvider} from "@material-ui/styles";
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

// Custom
import MuiTheme from "./base/MuiTheme";
import Main from "./Main";

ReactDOM.render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={MuiTheme}>
        <CssBaseline/>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Main/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>,
    document.getElementById("root"));
```

Webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "../..", "src", "client", "js", "index.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "../..", "dist", "js"),
        filename: "index.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                exclude: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader"
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader"
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: {}
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'assets/fonts'
                    }
                }]
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".css", ".scss", ".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".otf"],
    },
    target: "web",
    context: __dirname,
    stats: {
        colors: true,
        reasons: true,
        chunks: true,
    },
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "romys-hairstyling",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Official page for Romy's Hairstyling.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:react": "webpack --config ./config/webpack/webpack.config.js",
    "build:scss:base": "sass src/client/scss/base/_index.scss dist/css/base.css",
    "copy:html": "node ./scripts/copy.js ./src/client/index.html ./dist/index.html -f",
    "copy:images": "node ./scripts/copy.js ./src/client/assets/images ./dist/images -Rf",
    "watch": "npm-run-all -p watch:react watch:scss:base watch:html watch:images -l",
    "watch:react": "webpack --config ./config/webpack/webpack.config.js --watch --watch-aggregate-timeout 500 --watch-poll 1000 --info-verbosity verbose",
    "watch:scss:base": "chokidar \"./src/client/scss/base\" -c \"npm run build:scss:base\" --verbose --initial",
    "watch:html": "chokidar \"./src/client/index.html\" -c \"npm run copy:html\" --verbose --initial",
    "watch:images": "chokidar \"./src/client/assets/images\" -c \"npm run copy:images\" --verbose --initial",
    "start:server": "nodemon ./src/server/server.js",
    "test:eslint:summary": "eslint -c ./.eslintrc ./src/client/js/index.js",
    "test:eslint:fix": "eslint --fix -c ./.eslintrc ./src/client/js/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Romy",
    "Hairstyling"
  ],
  "author": "Tomas Schlepers",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "chokidar-cli": "^1.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.11",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

As said I do not get any error messages whatsoever. I can also see in the compiled JS code that there are references to the Penna font, but when looking in the rendered DOM tree I nowhere see the defined custom theme.

Comment: What happens when you change `typegraphy` in your theme  with `typography`?

Comment: As simple as it sounds, it does not change the fact that it is not working .
However, I will try again all solutions I previously did, as I do not know when this typo occurred.

Comment: Combination of this typo and the switch back to MuiThemeProvider component in stead of ThemeProvider did the trick, thank you so much :)

Comment: No worries :) If you are using ThemeProvider with v3.9 you will need to perform the old bootstrap step https://v3-9-0.material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/#migration-for-material-ui-core-users

Answer (score 18):

Step 1

add your font files to the fonts directory (./fonts/Raleway-Regular.woff2)

Step 2

Import fonts into the code in woff/woff2 formats. Documentation stated ttf/woff/woff2 supports, but ttf have not worked for me.

https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/

```
import RalewayWoff2 from './fonts/Raleway-Regular.woff2';
import RalewayBoldWoff2 from './fonts/Raleway-Bold.woff2';

const raleway = {
  fontFamily: 'Raleway',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontDisplay: 'swap',
  fontWeight: 400,
  src: `
    local('Raleway'),
    local('Raleway-Regular'),
    url(${RalewayWoff2}) format('woff2')
  `,
};

const ralewayBold = {
  fontFamily: 'Raleway',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontDisplay: 'swap',
  fontWeight: 700,
  src: `
    local('Raleway'),
    local('Raleway-Bold'),
    url(${RalewayBoldWoff2}) format('woff2')
  `,
};
```

Step 3

Run this in the terminal to use loader in your build process that can handle loading files

```
npm install --save-dev file-loader
```

refer https://jimthedev.com/2016/07/28/using-google-fonts-in-webpack-and-react/

Step 4

Then define the font in the theme

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      'Raleway',
      '-apple-system',
      'BlinkMacSystemFont',
      '"Segoe UI"',
      'Roboto',
      '"Helvetica Neue"',
      'Arial',
      'sans-serif',
      '"Apple Color Emoji"',
      '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
      '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
    ].join(','),
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
        '@font-face': [raleway,ralewayBold],
      },
    },
  },
});
```

You can use the bold font that imported like this.

`font-weight: 700;`

Comment: Was doing everything the same however the key point that "ttf have not worked for me" from this answer applied to me too. Changed to .woff2 and worked first time. Thanks for mentioning this in the answer, hope this helps others as well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! To get TTF to work, all I had to do was follow the above except 
```import RalewayTTF from './fonts/Raleway.ttf;```
```src: `
    local('Raleway'),
    url(${RalewayTTF}) format('truetype')
  `,
```
and since I use typescript, I had to add a font.d.ts file with ```declare module '*.ttf';```

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to the comment above. `ttf` works but you have to specify the format as `truetype`. So it will look like this instead.

```js
import Raleway from './fonts/Raleway-Regular.tff';

const raleway = {
  fontFamily: 'Raleway',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontDisplay: 'swap',
  fontWeight: 400,
  src: `
    url(${Raleway}) format('truetype')
  `,
};
```

Comment: Changing 'ttf' to 'truetype' is what eventually worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add `unicodeRange`
Like this:

```
const myFont = { 
        unicodeRange:
        "U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF UTF-8",
    }
```